# How to type the arguments of a function that returns a function

Tags: typescript, axios

I am trying to create type definitions for various axios services for the resources in my app. I'd like to enforce a specific configuration type for specific services (e.g. a function that fetches one resource should have the `method` property to set `GET`). Here is what I have:

```
import { AxiosPromise } from 'axios';
import fetch from 'auth/FetchInterceptor';

type TFetchOneConfig = {
    url: string;
    method: 'GET' | 'get';
};

type TFetchOne = (
    id: number
) => ReturnType<(config: TFetchOneConfig) => AxiosPromise<any>>;

interface Service {
    fetchOne: TFetchOne;
}

const AccountService: Service = {
    fetchOne: (id) => fetch({ url: `/accounts/${id}`, method: 'GET' }),
};
```

where `fetch` is an `AxiosInstance`.

The problem I'm having is that I can provide any `AxiosRequestConfig` (e.g. `method: 'POST'`) to the `fetch` `AxiosInstance` in the `fetchOne` function. How do I enforce the `TFetchOneConfig` type as the configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, `fetch` is of type `AxiosInstance`, and that's it. If you want to enforce a different behavior to `fetch` - it should be of a different type. Means, you could write your own "copy" of the `AxiosIntance` interface, like this:

```
interface MyAxiosInstance extends AxiosInstance {
  (config: AxiosRequestConfig & TFetchOneConfig): AxiosPromise;
}
```

And then use this interface to type your `fetch`.